# How to change default application for XML files?

Tags: 15.10, default-programs, xml

I have Ubuntu 15.10

So changing the default application for XML files gets immediately overridden by the default browser and does not keep the changes.

How do you set Gedit as the default application for XML files?

EDIT: In case it's needed, I use GNOME as DE

Comment: Which way have you tried (and didn't work)?

Comment: 1) Right click properties and 2) setting default application for "application/xml" with terminal.

Comment: You might also try checking the files `~/.local/share/mimeapps.list` and `~/.local/share/mimeinfo.cache` - if necessary - changing or adding the entry `text/xml=gedit.desktop`

Comment: Does not work....

Comment: No help, but just wanted to let you know I'm experiencing the same issue. Must be a bug in 15.10. I already had ubuntu tweak installed, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Oh thank god, I have a solution.

First of all the problem is getting caused by "Default Applications" in "Settings" on "GNOME", in order to save the default application for something like browser it overrides whatever it has as default for a set off applications and creates a double entry under `~/.config/mimeapps.list`. This way the default application for that mimetype cannot be changed unless you manually delete the entry for it. To do it:

- edit the file: `~/.config/mimeapps.list`
- find the `[Default Applications]`
- delete `application/xml`, there is a 2nd entry under `[Added Associations]` which we want to keep
- save the file and exit
- go to any xml file and now the default application can be changed by going `Right Click` > `Properties` > `Open With`

This is probably a bug within GNOME.

Comment: if you don't have `~/.config/mimeapps.list`, look for `.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` as [Anthony Wong](https://askubuntu.com/questions/709124/how-to-change-default-application-for-xml-files#comment1156765_753593) pointed out in the answer below

Comment: For anyone as dumb as me: To find the proper file to edit, you need to go to your home folder,  then click View->show hidden files (or Ctrl+H). Then the .config folder will appear.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the Default application from `defaults.list`.

Open the defaults.list file in terminal by

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/applications/defaults.list
```

Search for `xml=firefox` if your default browser is Firefox and replace by `xml=gedit`.

That is

```
text/xml=firefox.desktop
```

to

```
text/xml=gedit.desktop
```

Enjoy!

Comment: I prefer to add the line under the `[Default Applications]` section in `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`, because this file is per-user. Changes in `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` will be overwritten by system update.

Comment: This did not work for me on 16.04 - I HAD to add the line also to my local mimeapps.list

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these pages in the official guides:

- Ubuntu Desktop Guide

  https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/files-open.html
- GNOME Help

  https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/files-open.html

Comment: That will not help... the problem is that default browser entry keeps overwriting the default application for xml files.

Comment: @cra0zy: Maybe you need to change it in the browser too. In Firefox: _Edit -> Preferences -> Applications_

Comment: This answer helped me.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite tool for changing **Default Applications** and/or **Open With...** options is the good old **Ubuntu Tweak** here:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak

Yes, it hasn't been updated for a long time, but **it still works**!
(Currently on Ubuntu 15.10)

Simply download and install this: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak/0.8.x/0.8.7/+download/ubuntu-tweak_0.8.7-1~trusty2_all.deb

Or add the PPA by tweaking for **trusty**.

Then you just need to start **Ubuntu Tweak** and go to **Admins** and then to **File Type Manager**, find the **file type** you need, **double click** on the entry, and there **add/remove** apps and/or set the **default**.

**Non-GUI way:**

Make sure that files

`~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list` 
`~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` `~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`

contain the required entry, e.g. `text/xml=gedit.desktop` and/or `application/xml=gedit.desktop`

Comment: Doesn't allow gedit to be set, that is I can select it, but after the dialog closes the system resets it back to default web browser.

Answer (score 0):

In GNOME 3.26:

- Right click the file you want to open
- Select "Properties"
- Click on the "Open With" tab
- Select the application
- Click on "Set as default"

Answer (score 0):

Go to file-

> .config/mimeapps.list

and Open it.
Then under default Applications, look for a line that starts with-

> application/xml

Change it to-

> application/xml=org.gnome.gedit.desktop;