# How to change the default application to open xml file in Ubuntu Bionic Beaver (development branch)?

Tags: gnome, default, default-programs

I follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90214/how-do-i-set-the-default-program) and [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/files-open.html) to change the default application. But it does not work.

I try to change to Text Editor as default application to open xml file but it does not change. By default it is firefox.

```
cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu Bionic Beaver (development branch)"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506615/how-do-i-change-which-application-opens-xml-documents-by-default?rq=1) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/709124/how-to-change-default-application-for-xml-files?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem:**

```
sellerp18@sellerp18-MS-7788:~/Desktop/pm_new$ cat -n  ~/.config/mimeapps.list | grep xml
     7  text/xml=firefox.desktop
     8  application/xhtml+xml=firefox.desktop
     9  application/rss+xml=firefox.desktop
    10  application/rdf+xml=firefox.desktop
    82  image/svg+xml=eog.desktop
    83  image/svg+xml-compressed=eog.desktop
   140  application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document=libreoffice-writer.desktop
   143  application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet=libreoffice-calc.desktop
   149  application/xml=org.gnome.gedit.desktop
   152  text/xml=firefox.desktop;
   153  application/rss+xml=firefox.desktop;
   154  application/rdf+xml=firefox.desktop;
   223  image/svg+xml=eog.desktop;
   224  image/svg+xml-compressed=eog.desktop;
   272  application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
   275  application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
   283  application/xml=sublime-text.desktop;libreoffice-writer.desktop;
```

**Solution:**

I executed the following command to remove the default application from the file `~/.config/mimeapps.list`

```
 sed -i '/xml/d'  ~/.config/mimeapps.list
```

After that, right-click on a .xml file, choose Properties, and click the "Open with" tab.